# Word perfect(.wpd) support for aspose.words generated docx rtf

Tags: rtf, aspose.words, wordperfect

I am trying to create a "rtf" file using Aspose.Words to open the "rtf" file in Corel Draw Word Perfect.

When I am doing this, the "rtf" content open perfectly in Microsoft Word but doesn't open correctly in the Word Perfect Software. The text is not displaying at all in the Word Perfect software.

I wanted to know that does aspose.words support only Microsoft word based documents? How can I use Aspose.words to create .wpd(word perfect) documents.

Right now if I save the generated .docx file using aspose.words in .rtf format and then open the same in word perfect selecting the convertion option as Microsoft word 2007/2010. It opens correctly.

But that is not my business requirement. I need to open the word perfect document directly without manual conversion from Microsoft word to Word perfect.

Please let meknow if there is any way in Aspose. words to support Word perfect files directly.

Answer (score 1):

Aspose.Words does not support Corel Word Perfect. This feature is in plans but no release date is available at the moment.

I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: We regret to share with you that currently there is no further news about the Support of Corel Word Perfect in Aspose.Words and the implementation of this feature has been postponed for now (_No ETA is currently available_). We suggest you please post a thread in [Aspose.Words' Forum](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). This way we will keep you informed of any developments and you will be notified via your thread in Aspose.Words as soon as this feature is supported. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.